# Why IE browser preference language doesn't work

Tags: browser, language

All, I changed my web browser language to `Russian` by following [this post](http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/Change-The-Default-Languages-In-Ie9_6.htm) expect the web page display with Russian language. But it doesn't work. I don't know if I miss something. If anyone know .please kindly help to tell me .thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the browser?

Comment: Yes. I already restarted and test it .the page remained the same language `English`